# Verifying Signtatures, verifying returns false

Tags: java, dsa

I've searched forums and answers but I can't figure out my problem, I am trying to verify a signature , but it always returns false, am I doing something wrong? I generate the key, sign it and then verify it (the byte arrays are not null)

```
public void Keygen()  throws java.rmi.RemoteException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, SignatureException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException {
    KeyPairGenerator Keygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
    Keygen.initialize(1024, random);

    KeyPair pair = Keygen.generateKeyPair();
    priv = pair.getPrivate();
    pub = pair.getPublic(); 
}

public byte [] sign (int k)throws java.rmi.RemoteException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, SignatureException, InvalidKeyException , NoSuchProviderException
    Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN"); 
    dsa.initSign(priv);
    String data = "aa";
    byte[] b = data.getBytes();
    dsa.update(b);
    realSig = dsa.sign();        
    key = pub.getEncoded();
    return realSig;     
}

public int Versig(byte [] sigkeys)  throws java.rmi.RemoteException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, SignatureException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException{
    byte [] pkb = getenckey();

    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
    PublicKey pubKey = kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(pkb));              

    /* create a Signature object and initialize it with the public key */
    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN");
    sig.initVerify(pubKey);

    String data2 = "bb";
    byte[] c = data2.getBytes();
    sig.update(c);

    boolean verifies = sig.verify(sigkeys);
    System.out.println("1  " + verifies);
    if (verifies == true) {
        System.out.println(" 2 " + verifies);
        return (1);
    } else {
        return (2);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are signing `String data = "aa";` in sign method while verifying `String data2 = "bb";` so the signature verification will return false.

digitally signing the data to check it's integrity (which means no alter to the data).

I hope this could help!